# Why will VBA not return values until I open a source file, which is open during macro execution?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following line to do an INDEX/MATCH operation:

```
Range("F2:F" & TotalRowsSQL).Formula = "=INDEX('PATH\" & RåfilDate & "HørkramRå.csv'!AB2:AB" & TotalRowsRAW & ",MATCH(A2,'PATH\" & RåfilDate & "HørkramRå.csv'!A2:A" & TotalRowsRAW & ",0))"
```

Note that in reality, "PATH" is a true path...

Let me type a pseudo-code to help you make sense of that:

```
Range(MyRange).Formula = "=INDEX('FullPathToDifferentFile'!RangeInThatFile,MATCH(LookupValue,'FullPathToDifferentFile'!RangeInThatFile,0))"
```

When this is run the there are no exceptions, but when I open the file where the formula was executed only N/A has been returned.

Excel gives me a dialogue box that tells me that I can update the return values, and when I do it explains that the "different file" (called RåfilDate & "HørkramRå.csv") must be open in order to update the values. Opening the file immediatly fills the fields with all the expected values, showing my INDEX/MATCH to be written correctly...

The mystery is:
The file *is* open during the macro execution!
So I cannot understand why the fields aren't filled during the macro execution?

EDIT:
A theory was that the formula evaluated correctly during execution but returns N/A **after** macro execution. During execution I can *see* that it says N/A in all the fields. Regardless it was attempted to set:

```
Range("F2:F" & TotalRowsSQL).Value = Range("F2:F" & TotalRowsSQL).Value
```

This only resulted in the fields containing "N/A" as text rather than return from formula...

It looks to me like the open file is ignored during macro-execution, I just don't know why.

EDIT2:
It has been attempted to resolve the formula in VBA directly. I used the following code:

```
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim wb2path As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    
    wb2path = "MyActualPath"
    
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(wb2path)
    Set sh = wb1.ActiveSheet
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    
    wb1.Activate
    
    For x = 2 To TotalRowsSQL
        Range("F" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(path & "!AB2:AB" & TotalRowsRAW, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(A2, path & "!A2:A" & TotalRowsRAW, 0))
    Next x
    
    For x = 2 To TotalRowsSQL
        Range("G" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(path & "!AC2:AC" & TotalRowsRAW, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(A2, path & "!A2:A" & TotalRowsRAW, 0))
    Next x
    
    For x = 2 To TotalRowsSQL
        Range("H" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(path & "!AU2:AU" & TotalRowsRAW, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(A2, path & "!A2:A" & TotalRowsRAW, 0))
    Next x
```

This unfortunatly only resulted in the following exception:

"run time error 1004: unable to get the match property of the worksheetfunction class"

I don't know why the match function isn't being accepted.

EDIT3:
It has been attempted to correct the code in the following way:

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

Windows(Today & "HørkramProducentNavn").Activate
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

Windows(RåfilDate & "HørkramRå.csv").Activate
Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook

wb1.Activate

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = wb1.ActiveSheet

Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction


For x = 2 To TotalRowsSQL
    sh.Range("F" & x).Value = wf.Index(wb2.Sheets(1).Range("AB2:AB" & TotalRowsRAW), wf.Match(sh.Range("A" & x), wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & TotalRowsRAW), 0))
Next x

For x = 2 To TotalRowsSQL
    sh.Range("G" & x).Value = wf.Index(wb2.Sheets(1).Range("AC2:AC" & TotalRowsRAW), wf.Match(sh.Range("A" & x), wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & TotalRowsRAW), 0))
Next x

For x = 2 To TotalRowsSQL
    sh.Range("H" & x).Value = wf.Index(wb2.Sheets(1).Range("AU2:AU" & TotalRowsRAW), wf.Match(sh.Range("A" & x), wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & TotalRowsRAW), 0))
Next x
```

Note that both workbooks are already open, but has no variable attached to them, at the start of this code. It has been tested that the correct windows do indeed activate when the Windows().Activate methods are called.

It throws the exception 1004 "Unable to get Match property of Worksheet function class"

This leads me to believe somthing is wrong with the arguments inside the Match statement, and debugging revealed something strange:

It threw the exception while x = 5. I would have thought x = 2, but no, it's 5. Wouldn't this mean the code was executed correctly for x= 2, 3 and 4 ?

Now just to be clear, the debugger tells me that x = 5 and that TotalRowsRAW = 25868. So they're both real numbers, and to my understanding the arguments in the Match statement should be valid?

By the way, I went to wb1 to check and see if it had figured out the first columns row 2, 3 and 4, but no. These fields are empty.

- Thanks again for the help, I feel that I have a bit of a mystery on my hands...

Addendum: Goodness, would it give that exception if there *is* no match?? I checked, and that *is* the error it gives if there is no match!

Still odd that there is nothing in fields F2, F3 and F4 once the error occurs... Regardless, I'm going to try and implement Application.Match instead of WorksheetFunction.Match, since it doesn't throw an exection but just an N/A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because the values in the cells stay as formula and a direct reference to the other workbooks.

Try to add a

```
Range(MyRange).Value = Range(MyRange).Value
```

after writing the formulas to convert them to values.

That way you will end up with the actual values and no reference to the other workbooks.

Edit:

Based on the problem, maybe if you try to do the calculation inside of the vba instead of using the formula, with something like this:

```
Sub index_match()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim wb2path As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim indexRange As Range
    Dim matchRange As Range
    Dim matchValue As String
    
    wb2path = "" 'Add FullPathToDifferentFile
    
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set sh = wb1.ActiveSheet 'Worksheet to place the final values, can be also wb1.Sheets("nameofdesiredworksheet")
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(wb2path)
    wb1.Activate
    
    Set indexRange = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AB2:AB" & TotalRowsRAW) 'Sheet1 needs to be updated to FullPathToDifferentFile sheet
    Set matchRange = wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & TotalRowsRAW) 'Sheet1 needs to be updated to FullPathToDifferentFile sheet
    matchValue = sh.Range("A2") 'Range with value for match formula
    
    For x = 2 To TotalRowsSQL
        sh.Range("F" & x).Value = wf.Index(indexRange, wf.Match(matchValue, matchRange, 0))
    Next x

End Sub
```

Maybe some values needs to be adjusted, but I think it should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks that seems logical to me as well, but doesn't work. I can physically see it says N/A *during* execution, but I tried regardless. The result is that it says "N/A" as text in Excel now, rather than be a formula returning "N/A". I will update my question with this having been attempted.

Comment: I see, maybe doing the calculation inside the VBA could work. I edited my answer to include that.

Comment: Hello, I tried to do as you say, but I encounter the following exception:

"run time error 1004 unable to get the match property of the worksheetfunction class"

I will update my question to reflect this including the code that I used to adapt your solution. Perhaps you can see some error in it that I am missing? Thanks again.

Comment: Sure! Lets try adjusting the lines inside of the 3 For loops from this:
`Range("F" & x).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(path & "!AB2:AB" & TotalRowsRAW, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(A2, path & "!A2:A" & TotalRowsRAW, 0))`
to this: 
`sh.Range("F" & x).Value = wf.Index(wb2.Sheets(1).Range("AB2:AB" & TotalRowsRAW), wf.Match(sh.Range("A2"), wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & TotalRowsRAW), 0))`

Comment: Hi, I see some og the silly mistakes in my code and have fixed it. I am also adapting your changed line. Unfortunatly I get the same exception... I will update my question once again with my adaptation (hopefully without silly mistakes this time) of your solution.

Comment: I was checking again and as you mention, maybe the error could be because of no match. Try to add an `On Error Resume Next` before each `sh.Range("F" & x).Value` in each For Loop to see if it bypasses it. Also, I notice that in some cases, using the variable wf for the functions do not work as expected. If it keeps failing, try changing `wf.Index and wf.Match` for `Application.WorksheetFunction.Index and Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`